# how to set the rw permission for log files managed by syslog?

Tags: freebsd, syslog

I'm working on freebsd (but I think it's the same as on linux), and I'm using syslog to manage my log files, as defined in /etc/syslog.conf:

```
local1.notice                                   /var/log/my.log
```

I noticed that my.log will have 600 access permission by default, but I do want to have 666 permission. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files are not really managed by syslog; it merely writes to them.  You are supposed to create them first, with appropriate permissions.  So, first, set the permissions for the existing file by hand ("chmod 666 /var/log/my.log").  If you do not need log rotation - you're done.  If you do need log rotation, add the file to /etc/newsyslog.conf and set the mode there.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Another problem is that, if that file doesn't exist, when syslogd starts, it'll create the log file with permission 600. I confirmed this by restarting syslogd using "kill -HUP ...". How can I configure syslogd so that when it (re)starts it can create the log file with 666? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can; at least I couldn't spot anything in the man page.  Just make sure to create the files before starting syslogd.

Comment: That sounds the only approach. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$FileCreateMode 0666
local1.notice                                   /var/log/my.log
```

Follow the below link.

http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_filecreatemode.html